# Prove $∃x(∀y(\text{$5x+4y$ is even}))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I’m trying to solve this question but I’m not sure if I’m going correctly.

I know it’s false, so I tried to prove it defining which is odd (2k + 1) and which is even (2k) . Then I started working on the numbers, considering x and y as even, which would result in an odd result. Am I on the right the path?

Comment: Take $x$ to be any  even integer.

Comment: If x,  y are even then the result is even....

Comment: Your original question was incorrect. I fixed it. In the future, please do not put brackets carelessly otherwise you get meaningless statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outermost quantifier is $\exists$, so you're supposed to come up with one $x$ that satisfies $\forall y(2\mid5x+4y)$. We can take $x=0$. I will let you continue from here.

Comment: Oh, I see. But if I consider x as 0, I would have to consider y as an even too, right?

Comment: @FellipeBrancaccio No. $y$ must be able to take on any integer, including the odd ones, and still make the proposition true. However, since it is multiplied by $4$, $4y$ will always be even anyway.

Comment: Ooooh, thank you! Know I get it. The proof is straight to the point

Answer (score 1):

Write the expression as $4(x+y)+x$, so we can see that it is even precisely when $x$ is even. Thus the statement becomes "there exists $x$ such that for all $y$, $x$ is even", which is obviously true: just take any even $x$.